# Configuration Nginx for Microservices Api-Gateway

Tags: nginx, microservices, gateway, api-gateway

I want to proxy request to current network interface hostnames with Nginx such as:

url `/catalog/categories/...` proxy to hostname `catalog:8080` with url `/categories/...`
url `/vitrine/products/...` proxy to hostname `vitrine:8080` with url `/products/...`

Is any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration should look like this:

```
    http {
            ...    
            server {
                    listen 80;
                    server_name yourdomain;
    
                    set $mycatalog catalog:8080;
                    set $myvitrine vitrine:8080;
            }
        
            location ~ ^/catalog/categories/(.*)$ {
                    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                    proxy_pass http://$mycatalog/categories/$1$is_args$args;
            }

            location ~ ^/vitrine/products/(.*)$ {
                    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                    proxy_pass http://$myvitrine/products/$1$is_args$args;
            }
    }
```